# docker-compose: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: docker, postgresql, heroku, amazon-rds

I'm trying to make a few containers that are started by a docker-compose to work with a remote AWS database (managed by Heroku). I configured the envs as shown bellow:

```
    environment:
      - PG_HOST=xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
      - PG_USER=xxx
      - PG_PASS=xxx
      - PG_DBNAME=xxx
      - PG_PORT=5432
```

My problem is that the app recognizes the envs and returns a 'success' message as: `Ready hosting xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com to port 5432 !`
 but follows with a driver fail to `pq: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<gateway>", user "xxx", database "xxx", SSL off`

I've tried copying a custom pg_hba.conf as follows to the container's volume `/var/lib/postgresql/data`:

```
local   all             all             all                     trust
host    all             all             all                     trust
```

Also tried specifying the container's network_mode as `network_mode: host`, but it fails the same way.